# What will be the best caching system for wordpress blog which has more than one million blog posts?

Tags: posts, cache, server-load

I am trying to optimize a wordpress site which has more than one million blog post. I have used ngnix as many of them have recommended as it is one of the best server.

I am trying to find what will be the best caching software which will be best for such blog?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using nginx along with varnish. Varnish is a caching mechanism which runs on top of Apache/nginx. You can configure it to purge the cache after a specific time if you have users updating content often.

In terms of server configuration, I would recommend Amazon Web Services' EC2. This will allow you to easily scale up as needed. I would not install the database on the EC2 instance, and instead would use Amazon Web Services RDS - which is a load balanced Database server.

[Varnish Manual](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/)

[WordPress/Varnish Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/optimizing-wordpress-with-varnish-and-w3-total-cache--cms-21136)

Comment: What server configuration would you recommend?
And say I dont want to use AWS RDS then can I use EC2's other instance for DB?
Once instance will have the content and the other will have the db?

Will having db in localhost than on remote server effect speed of the website any way?